# Pivot table with no calculation

Tags: excel, text, pivot

I am a question about how to do something in excel with Pivot tables.

I have data that looks like this:
[image]

I want a pivot table (I will add more policies and more targetted options constantly) that let me filter by policy type, hierarchy, and policy status and I want to show Policies in column A and the targetted options in row A and for the values, I was expecting just 1 or 0 because all I want to show is the targeted action for each policy ad filter them. 
So it can look something like this:

[image]

So then I can see that Policy 1 has targetted option E1, E2, E3, E4 and E5 and filter with the other information.

until now I have tried with normal pivot (does not work) and with Power Query application following this tutorial here:
https://www.danbp.org/p/en/node/127
and try to play in that Power Query window to see if I can do it, but even when I chose "count" so it can represent the binary information I want it does not look like the table I need.

All the information I have si text, no numbers for calculations, that why the power query.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Unpivot your source data, so you have a normalised table with multiple rows, one for each targetted option.

This can be done easily with Power Query, and you will find many answered questions and tutorials for this if you search.

The normalised data can then be used in a Pivot table to have the targetted values in the pivot table columns.

- Take the data in your screenshot.
- unmerge the cell with the text "Targeted" and replace it with one value per column, for example T1, T2, T3 etc.
- Load the data into Power query
- Select all but the T1, T2, T3 etc columns
- On the Transform ribbon select Unpivot > Unpivot other columns
- Rename the columns called Attribute and Value
- Load the query into the worksheet
- Build a pivot table from the query result table